# Is $U\times_SY$ dense in $X\times_SY$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Given two morphisms of schemes $X\to S$ and $Y\to S$, suppose $U$ is an open subscheme of $X$ and $U$ is dense in $X$, is $U\times_SY$ dense in $X\times_SY$?

Comment: Not necessarily, let $S=X=\mathbb{A}^1$, let $U=\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}$ and $Y=\{0\}$, then $X\times_S Y=Y$ and $U\times_S Y=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Roland That seems like a perfectly fine answer to me.

Comment: @Arthur Thank you! I know few examples about algebraic geometry, I scan a textbook and find you are right.

Comment: @Roland If $X$ is irreducible, $X\to S$ is proper, $Y\to S$ is projective,  is $U\times_SY$ dense in $X\times_SY$?

Comment: @Borntobeproud My example satisfies all these extra assumptions.

Comment: @Roland Does here $\Bbb A^1$ denote $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb Z}$?

Comment: $\mathbb{A}^1_T$ for $T$ whatever base scheme you want.

Comment: @Roland But $\{ 0\}$ is not a closed subset of $\Bbb A^1_k$!

Comment: Of course it is... $\{0\}$ is the origin of the affine line. This correspond to the ideal $(X-0)$.